# Tcl: Include .so file in the starkit

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, .so, starkit

How do we wrap a `.so` file(externally created) in the starkit (.vfs ) file in tcl?

I created an explicit package and also the packageindex file and kept it in the /lib folder. However when I use packagre require it is not able to recognize the `.so` file.

Comment: Is this library a Tcl package implementation, or a _dependency_ of a package implementation?

Comment: The library is not a Tcl package implementation. The library is created by me by putting the .so file in it. The .so file is created by compiling c code through swig.